# RESTEasy ExceptionMapper not working with Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, resteasy

We use Spring Boot for integration tests and  RESTEasy for the REST URLs. I configured a ExceptionMapper for BadRequestException as I had added a test case for the exception thrown when bad request is sent. To suppress the RESTEasy exception thrown as a result, I added a BadRequestExceptionHandler that extends RESTEasy's ExceptionMapper. I was using '@SpringBootApplication' but added '@ComponentScan' with includeFilters setting the type to ANNOTATION and value to Provider.class. I have marked my handler class as @Component and so Spring is able to create the bean (autowiring worked) but RESTEasy is not picking this handler and I continue to see the exception in logs.

Can someone point out what I am doing wrong?

```
@Provider
@Component
public class BadRequestExceptionHandler implements ExceptionMapper<BadRequestException> {
    @Override
    public Response toResponse(BadRequestException exception) {
        return Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST)
                      .entity(exception.getMessage())
                      .build();
    }
}

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(includeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ANNOTATION, value = Provider.class))
public class TestApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
...
}
```

Thanks,
Paddy

Answer (score 2):

I know it is not directly related to your question, but this might actually solve your problem. It is possible to build Spring Boot REST applications by using RESTEasy as JAX-RS implementation by using this RESTEasy Spring Boot starter:

**com.paypal.springboot:resteasy-spring-boot-starter**

See the project website: https://github.com/paypal/resteasy-spring-boot/

Answer (score 1):

I was using a custom Undertow embedded server using custom JaxRs application class (already declared before my task started, so felt better to reuse it). So I had to set a Provider Factory configured with my custom exception mappers and set the provider factory on the Resteasy deployment object. Here is the code:

```
ResteasyDeployment deployment = new ResteasyDeployment();
ResteasyProviderFactory providerFactory =
            ResteasyProviderFactory.getInstance();
providerFactory.addExceptionMapper(BadRequestExceptionMapper.class); // My custom exception mapper
deployment.setProviderFactory(providerFactory);
```

Thanks,
Paddy